# Perform FFT periodic and aperiodic correlation on 2D arrays with Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, correlation

I am writing Matlab script to perform cross correlation on 2D matrix,does anyone know how to do this with fft2 function in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be quite a lot of information/discussion about doing this: try [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/11947), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253984/linear-convolution-of-two-images-in-matlab-using-fft2), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396814/cross-correlation-in-matlab-without-using-the-inbuilt-function).